# Android StAX Cursor Parser - could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance

Tags: java, android, stax

I'm using `AsyncTask` to download and parse XML content from i-net. Downloading and parsing of the xml happens in `doInBackground()` method. The **"dalvikvm"** encounters a problem - it could not find a method.

Here is the log of **LogCat:**

```
06-30 13:26:41.148: DEBUG/dalvikvm(507): GC freed 796 objects / 68088 bytes in 112ms

06-30 13:26:41.667: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Displayed activity com.news.reader/.SplashScreen: 5305 ms (total 63417 ms)

06-30 13:26:45.097: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.news.reader/.DirBgNewsReader }

06-30 13:26:45.418: ERROR/dalvikvm(507): Could not find method javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance, referenced from method com.news.reader.DirBgNewsReader.parse

06-30 13:26:45.427: WARN/dalvikvm(507): VFY: unable to resolve static method 104: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;.newInstance ()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory;

06-30 13:26:45.427: WARN/dalvikvm(507): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x0013

06-30 13:26:45.427: WARN/dalvikvm(507): VFY:  rejected Lcom/news/reader/DirBgNewsReader;.parse (Ljava/lang/String;)V

06-30 13:26:45.427: WARN/dalvikvm(507): Verifier rejected class Lcom/news/reader/DirBgNewsReader;

06-30 13:26:45.439: WARN/dalvikvm(507): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/news/reader/DirBgNewsReader;)

06-30 13:26:55.217: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

06-30 13:26:55.217: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4396eb68 com.news.reader/.DirBgNewsReader}

06-30 13:27:00.300: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{43814048 com.news.reader/.SplashScreen}
```

Could some one to help me and explain why it couldn't find the specified method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Could%20not%20find%20method%20javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=android%20Could%20not%20find%20method%20javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a10d912dc7bd8317&biw=1065&bih=700), I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/regexml/issues/detail?id=5) and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/).

Looks like StAX is not available on Android, but that an "equivalent" [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) is available.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Blog Post simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up](https://massaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/) (the answer by [dleerob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783198/dleerob) and [Triminmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2092587/trinimon)) helpful because it explains what Simple XML is doing:

> Now these are some odd errors ... in a nutshell, right here is where Simple XML works some reflection magic to see what classes it can actually use to serialize your XML. Simple XML was made to work essentially anywhere (which is why it works on Android 1.5) and this reflection code tells it what its current platform gives it to work with. It also caches the result of this reflection so you will only see these error messages appear once and then Simple XML has automatically ‘reconfigured’ itself, if you like.