# Android FasterXML parser - dependency on javax.xml.stream.events package

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am trying to use FasterXML (http://wiki.fasterxml.com/) Streaming API in my android app. As part of parsing logic, I needed to use following classes which are part of stax-api-1.0.1.jar which I added to 'Android dependencies' (libs).

```
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;
```

My class gets compiled fine, but when I try to run on simulator it gives me following error:

"
trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
"

I am using API 8 (target). Is there a work-around to use these javax classes..?

Comment: stax isn't available in Android. In general you can't use javax classes. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545052/android-stax-cursor-parser-could-not-find-method-javax-xml-stream-xmlinputfact

Comment: Thank you dmon. I also found the same in my research after I posted this question.